# How can I measure peak memory usage?

Tags: memory, glibc

I have a C++ program. I want to know the peak memory usage of this program. I tried using `memusage` from the GNU C library, but the result is not the same as on Windows. Why is that?

Here’s my test program:

```c
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <list>

int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

and here’s the `memusage` output showing 72,704 bytes used:

```
Memory usage summary: heap total: 72704, heap peak: 72704, stack peak: 0
         total calls   total memory   failed calls
 malloc|          1          72704              0
realloc|          0              0              0  (nomove:0, dec:0, free:0)
 calloc|          0              0              0
   free|          0              0
```

On Windows, I see an output of 0B.

Answer (score 3):

The GNU C library and GCC’s standard C++ library allocate heap memory and call `malloc` during program startup, before `main` is run at all; in your case, for these purposes:

- dynamic linking
- [vDSO setup](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/latest/source/elf/setup-vdso.h#L20) (all programs using the GNU C library on Linux do this)
- emergency exception handling pre-allocation (this is memory allocated so that exceptions can always be handled, even if no more memory can be allocated)

The first two don’t appear in `memusage`’s heap usage accounting, the 72,704-byte allocation corresponds to the C++ exception handling allocation. See also Valgrind’s output:

```
$ valgrind ./memtest
==822129== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==822129== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==822129== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==822129== Command: ./memtest
==822129== 
==822129== 
==822129== HEAP SUMMARY:
==822129==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==822129==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 72,704 bytes allocated
==822129== 
==822129== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==822129== 
==822129== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==822129== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If you want to see the overall memory usage, across all times of memory, a simple tool is `/usr/bin/time`:

```
$ /usr/bin/time ./memtest
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3148maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+117minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

This shows that the program used 3,148K of memory at its peak. (Use `/usr/bin/time` rather than `time` — the latter will use your shell’s built-in, which might not show this information.)

I imagine C++ programs perform similar operations on Windows, but the memory accounting may well be different, and perhaps startup heap usage isn’t included.